# How to fix a red underlined file with no errors appearing?

Tags: android, kotlin

my file in Android Studio is underlined in red but there are no errors when I open it...
The files were first called Muse_home, had to rename it to MipniHome for it to appear on AndroidManifest.xml.... MipniHome was what the file was originally called. Is it still somehome accessing the old file? How do I fix the red underlined museHome file?[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can’t use `//` for a comment in an XML file.

```xml
<!-- Make comments like this. --/>
```

2. Resource xml files are not allowed to have capital letters in their names.

Comment: thanks, just fixed that! But I still have the same error...